# Nested if statements in java

Tags: java

I am working on a user login page. I want the administrator to have access to the administrator section, but not the regular users. The following code works except that if a user besides the administrator logs in they get the wrong password error and are sent to the correct page. I assume there is something wrong with the nested if allowing the negative answer and the positive one. I would greatly appreciate any help with this matter.

```
        try {
        String sql="Select * from Users1";
        String host ="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Nash";
        String uName = "CON";
        String uPass = "smokes";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String user= userName.getText();
        String pwd= password.getText();
        while(rs.next()) {
        String uname=rs.getString("User_name");
        String pass=rs.getString("Password");
        String admin1=rs.getString("admin");

if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(pass)))
    { 
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    blankContent.setVisible(true);
    adminButton.setEnabled(false);
    receiptContent.setVisible(false);
    memberContent.setVisible(false);
    securityPanel.setVisible(false);
    }

        if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(pass))&&(admin1.equals("y")))
        {
            mainPanel.setVisible(true);
            blankContent.setVisible(true);
            adminButton.setEnabled(true);
            receiptContent.setVisible(false);
            memberContent.setVisible(false);
            securityPanel.setVisible(false);
         }
else 
    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "User name and password do"
                    + " not match!","ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

            }   
}   } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(program.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

**EDIT**
Following is edited code link --->
[New revised code link](http://pastebin.com/DGg7SB2B)

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does. I'm not sure what each line does, but your tabbing structure is rather convoluted. Try an autoformat; see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Well, obviously the issue is with the `&&(admin1.equals("y")`. If any one of those statements is false, it's immediately going to the `else`. You'd need to break that into a separate statement.

Comment: If None of these answers are working. Then make sure `admin1=rs.getString("admin");` is returning `y` **OR** `Y`. and Also make sure that you don't pass `null` while checking for `admin1`.

Comment: the admin part is working. the problem is that the error message comes up at the same time the main page does.

Comment: There is no way to happen like that if you implement the solution suggested.

Comment: I agree that it cant happen and yet...it is

Comment: Can you paste your current code in pastebin and edit the link.

Comment: I added it to pastebin I think this link will work.  [link](http://pastebin.com/DGg7SB2B)

Comment: @LindyKron I posted the answer. Let me know If the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything correct except you are missing one small glitch causing this problem `(From your pastebin code in your comment)`.

Your while statement is big issue here. It will keep on checking all records in your database.

use `break` once you got the desired user.

```
boolean isPass = false;
while(rs.next()){
    // Your user authentication 
    if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(pass)))
    { 
        if (admin1.equals("y")) {
            // do your admin operation
            break;
        } else {   
            // do your non admin operation
            break;
        }
    } else {
        // if authentication fails 
        isPass = true
    }
}
// Outside of while block
if(isPass){
    // if authentication fails show error message
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "User name and password do"
           + " not match!","ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
}
```

I showed this code snippet to show how to make use of break and be aware that you should also make this `break` for `else part` other wise it will keep on showing error message for all those records which became false for authentication in `if` part.

I will suggest to get your DB values from another method and do your authentication in another method.

Comment: I thought this would work...but no The problem persists

Comment: Where is the problem now? `break` supposed to work fine in your case if you apply it properly.

Comment: same problem...I think I applied it properly... error message still appears before the user can see main page.

Comment: Here is a link to the code with break added [link](http://pastebin.com/sfwQxZYX)

Comment: @LindyKron as I suggested already in my answer you have to exit loop from your `else` block also. Suppose you have 4 records and and 3 are not getting match then it will show you 3 error messages. That's why I told you to make two methods one for collecting DB values and one for authentication.

Comment: I added a break in else block. but now if it is a non admin account the just receive error message.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: you are welcome. Next time try to take care of these issue and debug the code. if you are using eclipse then you should definitely look at this. Debugger is your best friend. [eclipse Debug Tutorial](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your `else` out one level. The code formatting makes it hard to tell what's going on, but the else is on the admin `if` statement. Like this:

```
if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(pass)))
{ 
    if (admin1.equals("y"))
    {
        // ... admin
    }
    else
    {   
        // ... regular user
    }
}
else 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "User name and password do"
           + " not match!","ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
}
```

Comment: The way you added the 'else', the 'if' after it will never be evaluated true. You only get there if user name is wrong or password is wrong. But that's the first part of what it tests. There are several ways to rearrange it. I'd put one if for user and pw and then another test for the admin inside the braces. If the admin was true, do one thing, else do another.

Comment: Well...I'm not surprised my tabbing structure is messed up (I am new to java), I have tried all of the given suggestions but the problem persists.

Comment: @Lee Meador, thanks for the catch. I've edited my answer to be logically correct, sorry about that.

Comment: @LindyKron Try my edited code, Lee pointed out a logical error.

Comment: I tried your edited code but it did nothing to change my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(pass)))
    { 
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    blankContent.setVisible(true);
    receiptContent.setVisible(false);
    memberContent.setVisible(false);
    securityPanel.setVisible(false);
    adminButton.setEnabled(false);
          if(admin1.equals("y"))
                 adminButton.setEnabled(true);

    }


else 
    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "User name and password do"
                    + " not match!","ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

            }
```

Comment: I implemented this suggestion, it made my code look neater but did not fix the problem. I do appreciate everyone's efforts.